# Spell out Volume and Edition # in words - Biblatex in German?

Tags: bibliographies, biblatex

Is it possible to make Biblatex output the word "Second" (in German) instead of the number 2?

For  example here is my preamble:

```
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[
    sorting=none,     
  backend=biber,
    babel=other]{biblatex}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[german,american]{babel}
\addbibresource{references.bib}
```

and here is my bibliography entry:

```
@book{Cantor,
    author="Cantor, Moritz.",
    title="Vorlesungen über Geschichte der Mathematik.  (von 1200 - 1668).",
    language={German},
    volume={2},
    edition={2},
    address="Leipzig",
    publisher="Druck und Verlag von B.G. Teubner",
    date={1900},
    pagetotal="XII + 943 S.",
    hyphenation={ngerman},
    note="(in Germ.)",
}
```

However, when I run Babel+Biblatex on it, it outputs:

```
Moritz. Cantor. Vorlesungen uber Geschichte der Mathematik. (von 1200 - 1668). 
German. 2. Aufl. Bd. 2. (in Germ.) Leipzig: Druck und Verlag von B.G. Teubner, 
1900. XII + 943 S.
```

Whereis I want it to output "Zweite Auflage" and "Zweiter Band" instead of "2.Aufl." and "Bd. 2".

Does anyone know if this is this possible with biblatex?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use the `fmtcount` package for that purpose and redefine the field formats accordingly. For the edition, you can just redefine the `\mkbibordedition` macro. It is best to do this inside `\DefineBibliographyExtras`, since this is a language specific string:

```
\DefineBibliographyExtras{ngerman}{%
  \renewcommand*{\mkbibordedition}[1]{\Ordinalstringnum{#1}[f]}
}
```

For this to work, you need a bugfix for the current `fmtcount` version (the author of the package knows about this bug). See the minimal example below.

The volume is somewhat different, since the original definition (taken from `biblatex.def`) is

```
\DeclareFieldFormat{volume}{\bibstring{volume}~#1}% volume of a book
```

We need an auxiliary macro to have the integer transformed into an ordinal number, e.g. `\mkbibordvolume`, which we can then use in the “volume” field format:

```
\newcommand*{\mkbibordvolume}[1]{\Ordinalstringnum{#1}[m]}
```

Again, this is language specific, so the best would be to handle this as with `\mkbibordedition`. Thus, all in all, you get:

```
\newcommand*{\mkbibordvolume}{}
\usepackage{fmtcount}
\DefineBibliographyExtras{ngerman}{%
  \renewcommand*{\mkbibordedition}[1]{\Ordinalstringnum{#1}[f]}
  \renewcommand*{\mkbibordvolume}[1]{\Ordinalstringnum{#1}[m]}
}
\DeclareFieldFormat{volume}{\mkbibordvolume{#1}~\bibstring{volume}}
```

If you want to have “Band” instead of “Bd.” and “Auflage” instead of “Aufl.”, just use the option `abbreviate=false` (as in the example below). If you want everything else to be abbreviated, but not these two strings, use `\DefineBibliographyStrings` (see the manual for details).

I made a complete minimal working example from your code snippets:

```
\documentclass[german,ngerman]{scrartcl}
\listfiles
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{Cantor,
    author={Cantor, Moritz},
    title={Vorlesungen über Geschichte der Mathematik (von 1200--1668)},
    language={german},
    volume={2},
    edition={2},
    address={Leipzig},
    publisher={Teubner},
    date={1900},
    hyphenation={german}
}
\end{filecontents}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel,csquotes}

\usepackage[
  sorting=none,     
  backend=biber,
  babel=other,
  abbreviate=false
]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\newcommand*{\mkbibordvolume}{}

\usepackage{fmtcount}
\DefineBibliographyExtras{ngerman}{%
  \renewcommand*{\mkbibordedition}[1]{\Ordinalstringnum{#1}[f]}
  \renewcommand*{\mkbibordvolume}[1]{\Ordinalstringnum{#1}[m]}
}

\DeclareFieldFormat{volume}{\mkbibordvolume{#1}~\bibstring{volume}}

% Bugfix für fmtcount:
\makeatletter
\DeclareRobustCommand{\@OrdinalstringMgerman}[2]{%
   \@ordinalstringMgerman{#1}{\@@num@str}%
   \protected@edef#2{\protect\MakeUppercase\@@num@str}%
}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\@OrdinalstringFgerman}[2]{%
   \@ordinalstringFgerman{#1}{\@@num@str}%
   \protected@edef#2{\protect\MakeUppercase\@@num@str}%
}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\@OrdinalstringNgerman}[2]{%
   \@ordinalstringNgerman{#1}{\@@num@str}%
   \protected@edef#2{\protect\MakeUppercase\@@num@str}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\cite{Cantor}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: Actually, redefining the auxiliary macros inside `\DefineBibliographyExtras` is not always necessary, since `fmtcount` itself is aware of the different languages (it supports only English, Spanish, Portuguese, French,
French (Swiss), French (Belgian), German and Italian, though).

Comment: Sorry, will this change only the german numbers, or other languages too?

Comment: @drozzy: See my comment above (c;

Comment: Hm.. I mean is it possible to restrict this only to German language? Sorry for stupid question - I am still trying to understand all those commands!!

Comment: @drozzy, I don’t know if it is possible to limit this behaviour to one language. But I would not recommend to try this, since it is inconsistent.

Comment: Thank you - I've decided to stick with numbers. This seems like way too much trouble. I'll mark your answer accepted, so someone in the future might find it useful.